# Safari extension service worker does not wakeup after few days

Tags: mobile-safari, safari-extension

This only happens on iOS on all of the iPhones.

Safari extension works perfectly fine but after few days of inactivity it just stops. I see that content script still injects js that i want but service worker does not wake up.

Here is code that usually works

in content script i call

```
// wait for service worker to be ready
    const response = await browser.runtime.sendMessage({
      type: NIGHTLY_SAFARI_WAKE_UP,
      randomNumber: randomNumber
    })
```

in background service worker i respond

```
 browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, _sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type === NIGHTLY_SAFARI_WAKE_UP) {
      sendResponse(`I'm awake! ${request.randomNumber}`)
    }
  })
```

It works perfectly but after some time `sendMessage` call starts to respond with undefined and service worker does not work at all.